# Angular: ng-repeat adding value into array instead of overwriting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in my partial:

```
<div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div ng-repeat="phrase in phrases" ng-mobile-click="setChecked($index, phrase.phrase_id)">
        <div class="tile-inner" ng-bind-html="phrase.text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And at some point in the controller, I set a new element in the $scope.phrases:

```
$scope.phrases[swapHelper.indexToSwap] = newPhrase;
console.log($scope.phrases);
```

As soon as I set this new element, the view updates, but in an unexpected way: the element is inserted at the specified index, but the rest of the array is pushed back, so that it has one more element. After about 100-200ms, the old element that was supposed to be substituted is deleted. Can somebody explain this behaviour and how to prevent it?

I tried checking the array immediately after setting the new element by console.logging it, but it correctly displays with the right number of elements and the old element overwritten.

Comment: try log the value of `swapHelper.indexToSwap` and see if it changes

Comment: Can you try `$scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.phrases[swapHelper.indexToSwap] = newPhrase; })`? if it works I'll post an explaination.

Comment: morels: already did, the value is as expected, and the array also updates as expected. Just the rendered view is wrong

Comment: Muli Yulzary: got this error: main.js:13550 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: Does the swap happen in async callback?

Comment: Yes. Basically, I have a button with an ng-click directive, that function makes a http request and when that returns, it updates the array.

Comment: I also tried not waiting for the request to return and immediately updating on click, same problem